# bin2hex in PHP provides incorrect answer

Tags: php

With binary value `1111`, it should produce `F`.

But with the following code, it produces other results:

```
$answer = bin2hex('1111');
// $answer is 31313131
```

How can I obtain the desired HEX representation correctly ?

Comment: You thought it meant dual number instead of raw data. Is the misinterpretation of the ambiguous function name really such a common problem? What it's really for is [explained in the manual](http://php.net/bin2hex) still; and [comment #77038](http://php.net/bin2hex#77038) specifically that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get desired HEX representation, we can use the following codes:

```
$binary = '1111';
$answer = strtoupper(dechex(bindec($binary)));

echo $answer; // which produces "F"
```

Explanation: The function `bin2hex()` is for converting binary data into a hexadecimal string representation, but not for converting strings representing binary digits into hexadecimal. That's why we need to combine `bindec()` and `dechex()`.

Note: `strtoupper()` is optional.

---

Alternate solution:

PHP provides a cleaner way to convert number base:

```
$answer = base_convert($binary, 2, 16);
```

however, this function may lose precision. See [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.base-convert.php) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [printf()](http://www.php.net/printf) function to get the desired hexadecimal representation:

```
printf('%x', bindec('1111')); # f (lowercased)
printf('%X', bindec('1111')); # F (uppercased)
```

Comment: nice idea, can also use `sprintf()` to save output to a variable.